# MongooseServerSelectionError while trying to connect mongodb database using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lambda

We are trying to connect AWS Lambda Node.js function to the Mongodb Cluster within VPC.

It works fine with single IP so there is no issue of AWS related permissions.

When we used below connection string into mongoose.

```
const uri = 'mongodb://10.0.0.2:27001,10.0.0.3:27002/dbName?replicaSet=replicaSetName';
```

We are getting below error,

```
Response
{
  "errorType": "MongooseServerSelectionError",
  "errorMessage": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo06.server",
  "trace": [
    "MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo06.server",
    "    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:844:32)",
    "    at Mongoose.createConnection (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:285:17)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:17:31)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

I'm using below code to connect mongodb using mongoose client,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let conn = null;
const uri = 'mongodb://10.0.0.2:27001,10.0.0.3:27002/dbName?replicaSet=replicaSetName'

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (conn == null) {
        console.log(uri);

        conn = await mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            bufferCommands: false, // Disable mongoose buffering
            bufferMaxEntries: 0 // and MongoDB driver buffering
        });

        //connectionInstance connected
        conn.once('open', () => {
            console.info("MongoDb connected successfully");
        });
        mongoose.set('debug', true);

    }
    const M = conn.model('collectionName');
    const doc = await M.findOne();
    console.log(doc);
};
```

I need help to solve this issue.

Comment: Remove the slash after the DB name. `mongodb://0.0.0.0:00000,0.0.0.0:00000/dbName?replicaSet=replicaName`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have updated my question and we have already tried with removing the slash after the DB name but still no luck on it.

Comment: Can you connect with mongo shell using the same connectionString URI?